# Is there any prime ideal of any commutative ring that $R$ such that it is not generated by a prime element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a Principal Ideal Domain and $P$ be a nonzero ideal of $R$.Then $P$ is prime and $P\ne R$ iff $P$ is generated by a prime element.

But is there any prime ideal of any commutative ring that $R$ such that it is not generated by a prime element?

Comment: Yes, plenty: the ideal generated by $X$ and $Y$ in $F[X,Y]$ (polynomials in two indeterminates over the field $F$) is prime, but not principal.

Comment: how can I able to check that $F[X,Y]$ is prime and also $X$ and $Y$ are prime elements .

Comment: You only need to check that the *ideal* $I$ generated by $X$ and $Y$ is prime. It's maximal, actually, because it's almost obvious that $F[X,Y]/I\cong F$ which is a field.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to take ring witch is not PID. For example $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. There is a sequence of prime ideals $(x_1)\subset...\subset(x_1,...,x_n)$. Its easy to see that all but first of those ideals can't be generated by one element.